# Prove: $\det [T]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{B}}=\det [T]^{\mathcal{C}}_{\mathcal{C}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be ordered bases for $V$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation.

Prove: $\det [T]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{B}}=\det [T]^{\mathcal{C}}_{\mathcal{C}}$.

Comment: Do you know what is the relation between the two matrices?

Comment: Yes, but do you know that it implies there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $[T]^B_B=P^{-1}[T]^C_CP$? The matrix $P$ is a change of base matrix. And from here the statement is easy, because the determinant is multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean $\det [T]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{B}}=\det [T]^{\mathcal{C}}_{\mathcal{C}}$? In that case, you can find some invertible matrix $B$ such that

$[T]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{B}}= B^{-1}[T]^{\mathcal{C}}_{\mathcal{C}}B$

Take determinants on both sides, and use that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

Comment: I see. So have you seen any results besides the definition of matrix representations of linear transformations? Also, how have you defined the determinant?

Comment: @kreosnel It seems strange that you haven't seen the property used in the answer, but that you have seen the fact that $[T^{-1}]_B^B = ([T]_B^B)^{-1}$. One of the first things proven is that $[S \circ T]^C_A = [S]^C_B \cdot[T]^B_A$. From this equality, everything else follows (including the rule for inverses). So, in the present context, $[T]^C_C = [I]^C_B \cdot [T]^B_B \cdot [I]^B_C$, where $I$ is the identity map on the vector space. Or if we set $Q = [I]_C^B$, then $[T]_C^C = Q^{-1}\cdot [T]_B^B\cdot Q$.

Comment: @kreosnel Notice that $T = I \circ T$ So, $[T]_C^C = [I \circ T]^C_C = [I]^C_B[T]^B_C$. Now, write $T = T \circ I$. So, $[T]^B_C = [T \circ I]^B_C = [T]^B_B [I]^B_C$. Combine these two results.

Comment: @kreosnel I'm sorry, but I think you should try to prove that by yourself. Everything (and I mean everything) you need to know to derive the various rules is contained in the fact that $[S \circ T]^C_A = [S]^C_B[T]^B_A$ and $[\text{id}_V]_B^B = I_{n\times n}$ (of course with each function having appropriate domain and target space). You just have to use this carefully to particularly chosen transformations $S,T,$ and bases $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$. All of this can be found in any decent linear algebra textbook, for example Friedberg, Insel, Spence.